# What color format gnome terminal color pallete use?

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors

My question is as per title and more importantly, how to convert regular hex/rgb color format to the one that is used in gnome terminal color pallete (eg #26268B8BD2D2)?

Comment: You can also use the simpler #ffffff for white, #000000 for black, etc. But see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/122114/48-bit-colours) for more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GTK use **16-bit** color components. so **rgb** is represented as **rrrrggggbbbb**.

The example which you took is equivalent to #26268B8BD2D2 -> #268BD2 -> RGB (38,139,210)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! That gives me some ideas how to do the conversion

Comment: Glad that it helped you.